# Pagination with Vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm quite new to JavaScript, so apologies if this is obvious or if the question isn't clear.

I have a pagination assignment, and I have to limit a list of students to 10 per page using a function. I'm allowed a little jQuery, but absolutely no plugins.

Currently I have:

```
const numberOfStudents = $('.page .student-item').length;
const limitPerPage = 10;
var totalPages = Math.ceil(numberOfStudents / limitPerPage);
```

How do I go about creating a function using this? To limit the students. I was thinking of using a loop, but I've no idea where to start.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please take a minute to read [How To Ask A Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and consider updating your question.

Comment: I was able to find something that may help on google. This shows pagination but it does have some Typescript. At the very least, it should give you an idea on how to work on the problem. [jasonwatmore.com](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/08/07/javascript-pure-pagination-logic-in-vanilla-js-typescript)

Answer (score 2):

I wrote this small function some time back to handle paginating arrays for me. You shouldn't use it on very large arrays, but it does the job for relatively smaller ones. Its usage should be pretty self-explanatory:

```
function paginateArray(ary, perPage=10, pageNumber=1) {
  const start = perPage * (pageNumber - 1)

  const size = ary.length
  return {
    data: ary.slice(start, start + perPage),
    numberOfPages: Math.ceil(size / perPage),
    currentPage: pageNumber,
    dataLength: size
  }
}

paginateArray([1,2,3,4,5], 2, 1]
// {data: [1, 2], numberOfPages: 3, currentPage: 1, dataLength: 5}
```

Comment: Why shouldn't the OP use it on very large arrays? Seems pretty efficient to me. What would you suggest instead?

Comment: I guess I'm referring to *very* large arrays. Anything that could be returned from a backend that is 1e5+ entries should be paginated on the backend. But, because this is for an assignment and OP is admittedly new to Javascript, I'm sure those types of problems will crop up for him/her way later down the road :)

Comment: Ah, yes that makes sense. I thought you were referring to the algorithm itself being a bad choice for large arrays, not the fact that you don't want to send a large array over the network at one time.

Answer (score 0):

Is the assignment to paginate `.student-item`s whose DOM elements are already loaded onto the page? This isn't standard, but if that's the assignment, then I recommend hiding the `.student-item`s that are not on the "current page".

```
// All this code should run after the .student-item's are loaded.
// If this makes for an ugly flash of .student-item's that should not
// be shown, then you can hide the .student-item's by default in css,
// and let jquery force the .student-item to be shown.

function displayPage(pageNum) { // pageNum must be between 0 and totalPages-1
    $('.page .student-item').each(function(idx, studentEle) {
        if (idx >= (limitPerPage * pageNum) && idx < (limitPerPage * (pageNum+1))) {
            studentEle.show(); // student is on this page
        } else {
            studentEle.hide(); // student is NOT on this page
        }
    });
}

$('.page-select').on('change', function () {
    // example <select> element for the page.
    // Most likely you would want some links or buttons, not a <select> element, but this is just an example
    var selectedPage = $('.page-select option:selected').first().val();
    displayPage(selectedPage - 1);
});

displayPage(0);
```

Comment: @mhodges according to me, I suppose. That was an unfounded claim. :D
I removed that from the post since it wasn't really relevant anyway. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your are using jQuery to manipulate the DOM, and may not actually have have data directly at your disposal. This code not the best solution from a professional standpoint but I think fits what appears to be your educatioal situation.

```
var currentPage = 1;

// Hide every student beyond the first page
$('.student-item').each(function(i, student) {
  if (i >= limitPerPage * currentPage) {
    $(student).hide()
  }
});

// Manipulate the DOM to show the students on the new 'page'
function displayNewPage() {
  $('.student-item').each(function(i, student) {
    if (i >= limitPerPage * currentPage || i < limitPerPage * (currentPage - 1)) {
      $(student).hide();
    } else {
      $(student).show();
    }
  });
};

// Create a button with id 'page-left' for this work
$('#page-left').on('click', function() {
  if (currentPage > 1) {
    currentPage--;
    displayNewPage();
  }
  if (currentPage === 1) {
    $('#page-left').prop('disabled', true);
  }
  $('#page-right').prop('disabled', false);
});

// Create a button with id 'page-right' for this work
$('#page-right').on('click', function() {
  if (currentPage < totalPages) {
    currentPage++;
    displayNewPage();
  }
  if (currentPage === totalPages) {
    $(event.target).prop('disabled', true);
  }

  // Allow 
  $('#page-left').prop('disabled', false);
});
```